# API didn't match in php_printer module in Windows

Tags: php, apache, php-extension

I downloaded the php_printer extension from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ . But when i try to configure my php.ini file, a message pops-up saying that

```
PHP Startup: printer: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
```

I am using EasyPHP for Windows. The PHP version is 5.4.6 and that of Apache is 2.4.2

I went through other questions of similar kind but i am not server-admin or like so I don't have any idea of Command-Line PHP, and recompile things. Can anyone find me a good and easy solution to this.

PS: If the solution is not easy and i really have to recompile the PHP extension, please provide me with the steps how to do that on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the extension was compiled to work with php 5.3, and you are trying to use it with 5.4

One solution is to downgrade EasyPHP to php 5.3 to make it work.

Comment: I was thinking of that, anyway. Isn't there a way we can make it compatible with PHP4. Anything that you'd think of doing?

Comment: im not sure sorry, I don't use extensions too much